# LEFT JOIN query with COUNT takes so long to execute

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization, aggregate-functions, outer-join

I have 4 tables, **album**, **artist**, **song_cover** and **song**.
Am trying to join the 3 tables to the **album** table and include the total number of songs within each album.

The query I have so far returns results as expected but takes almost over a minute to execute.

```
SELECT frco_album.*,
COUNT(frco_song.song_id) AS TotalSongs, 
artist_aka, artist_address, 
cover_filename
FROM frco_album
LEFT JOIN frco_song ON frco_album.album_id = 
frco_song.song_album_id
LEFT JOIN frco_artist ON frco_album.album_artist = 
frco_artist.artist_id
LEFT JOIN frco_song_cover ON frco_album.album_cover_id = 
frco_song_cover.cover_id
GROUP BY frco_album.album_id
ORDER BY album_month DESC LIMIT 0, 20;
```

When I get rid of the **song** table `LEFT JOIN song ON album.album_id = song.song_album_id` and `COUNT(song.song_id) AS TotalSongs`, the query executes fast, as expected.

What am I doing wrong here?

EDIT: I've edited the question to include the tables and changed the query to reflect the actual rows in the tables.

[image: song_cover table]

[image: song table]

[image: artist table]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What are your table indexes? What happens when you remove the `ORDER BY`?

Comment: Without knowing more information it may be quite hard to help, such as the actual table structure, indexes, etc along with the amount of data in those tables. Do you have any actual statistics other than "almost over a minute" and "executes fast, as expected"?

Comment: Also, is `song.song_album_id`  and `album.album_id` the same data type? And can `song.song_album_id` ever be NULL?

Comment: Please add the result from an EXPLAIN..

Comment: I've edited the question to include the tables

Comment: Also changed the "artist_address" to "artist_slug", this shouldn't cause confusion.

Comment: How many lines are there in each table?

Comment: @Tomalak nothing changes if I remove the ORDER BY

Comment: @Kendle artist - 12,929 lines, song - 56,222, song_cover - 5,991 and album - 12,898 lines

Comment: @Tomalak song.song_album_id and album.album_id - same data type. song.song_album_id can't be null.

Comment: It's not a good idea to group by on one column when there are many columns selected. Also I would convert the join to a subquery containing the count by id and join that to album

Comment: @P.Salmon thanks, let me try that out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The left join will multiply rows and then you condense them back using group by. Assuming that there is one artist and cover per album I would try counting the songs inside the `select` clause:

```
SELECT album.*, artist_aka, artist_address, cover_filename, (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM songs
    WHERE song.song_album_id = album.album_id
) AS TotalSongs
FROM album
LEFT JOIN artist ON album.album_artist_id = artist.artist_id
LEFT JOIN song_cover ON album.album_cover_id = song_cover.cover_id
ORDER BY album_plays DESC
LIMIT 0, 20
```

Comment: You are a life saver. This works. Thank you very much.

For the actual tables above, I've made some changes to reflect the actual rows.


SELECT frco_album.*, artist_aka, artist_address, cover_filename, (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM frco_song
    WHERE frco_song.song_album_id = frco_album.album_id
) AS TotalSongs
FROM frco_album
LEFT JOIN frco_artist ON frco_album.album_artist = frco_artist.artist_id
LEFT JOIN frco_song_cover ON frco_album.album_cover_id = frco_song_cover.cover_id
ORDER BY album_month DESC
LIMIT 0, 20;

Comment: `<pet-peeve>` Yeah, but the prefix "frco_" is clutter that adds no useful info. `</pet-peeve>`

Comment: @rick prefixed table names are common e.g. if you install wordpress on an existing database then you end up with a bunch of `wp_...` tables.